# Problema con boton input, no puedo centrarlo HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

Hola estoy aprendiendo css y tengo un problema al centrar un botón de un formulario acá dejo el código para que vean. Muchas gracias!

codigo HTML :

```
<body>
    <footer>
        <section class="contacto">
            <h2>Contacto</h2>
            <form class="contacto" action="">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre:" maxlength="25" required name="nombre">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email:" maxlength="40" required name="email">
                <br/>
                <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje:"></textarea>
                <br>
                <input type="Submit" value="Enviar" name="btnEnviar">

            </form>
        </section>
        <section class="redes-sociales">

        </section>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Codigo CSS:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*PAra el formulario*/
.contacto{
    background: #fff;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;

}
/*Para los input del nombre y del email */
.contacto input[type="text"],
.contacto input[type="email"],
.contacto textarea{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #226fc1;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.contacto textarea{
    min-height: 120px;
    max-height: 300px;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
/*Cuando hacemos focus en los input de texto, email y el area de texto va a agregarse un marco para saber en que ventana esta el usuario*/
.contacto input[type="text"]:focus,
.contacto input[type="email"]:focus,
.contacto textarea:focus{
    border: 2px solid #43ce98;
}
/*para el boton*/
.contacto input[type="submit"]{
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid #43ce98;
    color:#43ce98;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 3px;

}
/*cuando el usuario pase el puntero por encima del boton se va a rellenar con color*/
.contacto input[type="submit"]:hover{
    background: #43ce98;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Brother, copia y pega tu código porque es más fácil que estar leyendo una imagen. Así te podríamos ayudar

Comment: ok es mi primera vez, gracias por contestar. Ahí lo edito.

Comment: Selecciona todo lo que es código y luego haz clic en las llaves { } para que te lo reconozca como código

Comment: Muchas gracias Hugo! Ahí lo edite!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brother, la forma más sencilla es meter el botón dentro de un div con alineación centrada

```
   <div style="text-align:center">
      <input type="Submit" value="Enviar" name="btnEnviar">
    </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Hugo funciono! esta forma es correcta a la hora de programar y que siga las reglas?

Comment: Lo que yo haría es crear una clase llamada "text-center" por ejempo, y así la llamo cada vez que necesite centrar el contenido. Si te funcionó, puedes votar a favor de la respuesta ;)

Comment: ok voy a intentar resolver eso, muchísimas gracias, si apreté en la flecha hacia arriba pero como no tengo 15 de reputación no cambia la puntuación :/.

Answer (score 0):

En mi experiencia, lo que hago es dentro del formulario, para cada input, crear un div padre con la clase .input-field (o .input-field-50 si quiero que ocupe la mitad).
Con esto consigo tener control absoluto sobre los inputs.

HMTL:

```
<form>
  <div class="input-field">
    <label>Usuario:</label>
    <input name="username"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.input-field,
.input-field-50 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Hoal Moises! me alegra que tomases tu tiempo para contestar y ayudar. Podrías aclarar mas tu respuesta? No se entiende muy bien que relación tiene tu respuesta con la pregunta, ni cual es la solución que propones. Aqui te dejo [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) por si te ayuda.